# Unable to install Docker Enterprise edition on EC2 Amazon linux 2

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ec2

Please I need assistance installing Docker EC2 Amazon Linux 2

After:

`yum -y install docker-ee docker-ee-cli containerd.io`

I receive:

> No package docker-ee available.
>   No package docker-ee-cli available.
>   No package containerd.io available.
>   Error: Nothing to do

I have also tried:

`sudo yum install /home/ec2-user/docker-ee-19.03.0-3.amzn2.aarch64.rpm`

I get:

> Cannot add package /home/ec2-user/docker-ee-19.03.0-3.amzn2.aarch64.rpm to transaction.
>   Not a compatible architecture: aarch64
>   Error: Nothing to do

[image: Screenshot from PuTTY]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you skipped the commands to install the docker repo. Mainly:

```
$ yum install -y yum-utils
$ yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    "$DOCKERURL/centos/docker-ee.repo"
```

These steps are from: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/centos/#set-up-the-repository

Answer (score 0):

Fritz -

You downloaded a package for the the wrong architecture. The aarch64 package is for ARM v8 based AMIs. Unless that's what you're running, you have the wrong package. Try to find the x86_64 package instead.

Cheers!